# php forcing type

Tags: php

I have a collegue who constantly assigns variable and forces their type.  For example he would declare something like so:

```
$this->id = (int)$this->getId();
```

or when returning he will always return values as such:

```
return (int)$id;
```

I understand that php is a loosely typed language and so i am not asking what the casting is doing.  I am really wondering what the benefits are of doing this - if any - or if he is just wasting time and effort in doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few benefits.

1. **Type-checking**.  Without type-checking, 0 == false and 1 == true.
2. **Sanitizing**. If you're inserting the value into an SQL query, you can't have SQL injection because string values are converted to zero.
3. **Integrity**. It prevents inserting invalid database data. Again, it converts to zero, so you won't be trying to insert a string into a integer field in a database.

Comment: +1, sanitizing is probably the most useful reason to do this.

Answer (score 1):

> To explicitly convert a value to
>   integer, use either the (int) or
>   (integer) casts. **However, in most
>   cases the cast is not needed, since a
>   value will be automatically converted
>   if an operator, function or control
>   structure requires an integer
>   argument.** A value can also be
>   converted to integer with the intval()
>   function.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.casting

> PHP does not require (or support)
>   explicit type definition in variable
>   declaration; a variable's type is
>   determined by the context in which the
>   variable is used. That is to say, if a
>   string value is assigned to variable
>   $var, $var becomes a string. If an
>   integer value is then assigned to
>   $var, it becomes an integer.
>
> An example of PHP's automatic type
>   conversion is the addition operator
>   '+'. If either operand is a float,
>   then both operands are evaluated as
>   floats, and the result will be a
>   float. Otherwise, the operands will be
>   interpreted as integers, and the
>   result will also be an integer. Note
>   that this does not change the types of
>   the operands themselves; the only
>   change is in how the operands are
>   evaluated and what the type of the
>   expression itself is.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

You can do something like this instead.

```
function hello($foo, $bar) {
    assert(is_int($foo));
    assert(is_int($bar));
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.assert.php